# C Array Equivalent in Swift

Tags: swift

How do I set a null character in a CChar array with Swift?

In C I can do this

```
char addrBuf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
addrBuf[0] = '\0';
```

How do I do it in Swift?

```
var addrBuf = [CChar]()
addrBuf = [CChar](count: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN), repeatedValue: 0)
addrBuf[0] = '\0'//build error, use ""
```

Comment: Could you please show the actual use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CChar is just an alias for Int8 use 0
0 is the int value for null char

Alternatively:

```
var addrBuf = [CChar]()
addrBuf = [CChar](count: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN), repeatedValue: 0)
addrBuf[0].value = "\0".utf8.first!.value
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will declare and init your variable in one step, as well as setting the first element to 0:

```
import Foundation

var addrBuf = [CChar](count: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN), repeatedValue: 0)
```